# Excel - return 1 for each row where an element exists in one of two columns

Tags: excel

How do I sum all occurrences in column C and D where at least one of the rows contain a number?

E.g if C4 or D4 contains 1-5, the formula should return 1 for that row. If neither contain a value, the row shouldnt be counted. I tried alot of things but I am new to excel, Im used to other programming languages.

in pseudo code:

```
sum = 0
for row in rows:
    if A>0 or B>0:
       sum += 1
return sum
```

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry, that doesn't do it. If i have a value in C5 and a value in D4, the result should be 2. It becomes 0 with your formula. Im using Google Docs by the way, But I guess its the same

Comment: Ah yes I missed the Or part, `=COUNTIF(C:C,">0")+COUNTIF(D:D,">0")-COUNTIFS(C:C,">0",D:D,">0")`

Comment: @ScottCraner the problem is, that formula adds 2 if both C and D contain a value, which it shouldnt.

Comment: Which the above then removes one for each time it is both. see: http://imgur.com/a/hLDiX

Comment: Hm, that's weird. In google docs, i get an error :O

Comment: Works for me: http://imgur.com/a/f20bS

Comment: Try typing the formula in by typing it.  Sometimes the comments creates errors.

Comment: I dont know man, my google docs doesnt even pick up on the syntax. It's supposed to be `;` as a separator, not `,` .. That's real weird.

Comment: Then change the `,` to `;`.  It has to do with local settings.

Comment: Ah, typing it by hand helped. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

you can try a following spreadsheet formula:

```
=IF(OR(AND(C1>=0; C1<=0); AND(D1>=0; D1<=5)); 1; 0)
```

It will be much easier and faster than coding it in VBA. Of course, if there is such a need, it can be coded in VBA.